# How to put cells into certain sections in a grouped table?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've got a class of object with a category property (`task.category`), which is set to an integer value (1, 2, or 3). I'd like to have a grouped table build itself by putting each `task` into the right section...

How do I get certain cell objects to be drawn in certain sections of a grouped table, based on one of their properties?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do that automagically. You still have to implement all necessary methods of `UITableViewDataSource`. In order for your datasource methods to provide correct data, you should build some suitable data structure first by grouping your tasks by category. The easiest way would be to build a NSDictionary with the category (wrapped in NSNumber) as key and an NSArray of corresponding tasks as value.

To build this dictionary, do something like this (not tested):

```
NSArray* keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1], [NSNumber numberWithInteger:2], [NSNumber numberWithInteger:3], nil];
NSArray* objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSMutableArray array], [NSMutableArray array], [NSMutableArray array], nil];
self.dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

for(Task* task in tasks) {    // if tasks is your array holding all tasks
    NSNumber* bucket = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:task.category];
    [[dict objectForKey:bucket] addObject:task];
}
```

The reason why we have to do this `NSNumber` boilerplate, is that you can't use primitive values (eg. integers) as dictionary keys.

Once you have this dictionary (`self.dict` in the code below), just implement the necessary `UITableViewDataSource` methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 3;    // supposing you have 3 categories
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSArray* tasks = [self.dict objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:(section + 1)]];
    return [tasks count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSArray* tasks = [self.dict objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:(indexPath.section + 1)]];
    Task* task = [tasks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // other stuff usually done here (create cell, set content of cell etc.)
}
```

Of course, this is just one possible approach, but I hope it helps to get you on the right track.

Comment: That sounds great; probably exactly what I need, thanks. Only problem is I can't figure out how to get the right task objects into the right arrays. In pseudocode, I want: `for each task object, add to the Category1 array if task.category == 1`.

Comment: I just updated my answer and added some sample code to build the dictionary. Maybe it's not the nicest way to do this, but it should work.

Comment: Ahhh, awesome. Okay. Quick question: `self.dict` doesn't exist yet... Where does that come from?

Comment: I don't know where your data (the tasks) come from, but you should consider to store them in some grouped format, so you don't have to completely re-group them again and again.. Ideally, you should store them in a format directly usable by the table view datasource (eg. dictionary as proposed above; 3 separate arrays etc.)

Comment: The tasks get pulled from an sqlite db, and then each field from the database is mapped to a property of the `task` class. I'm only doing that because it's what the sqlite examples I was drawing from used; I'm sure there's a better way to manage this stuff.

Comment: It's supposed to be a property of type NSDictionary*. It would definitely be out of scope of this comment to explain properties in detail. Have a look at http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html and maybe also http://theocacao.com/document.page/510 (or search stack overflow) - believe me, you will have to familiarize yourself with properties anyway sooner or later.. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, it appears to be an important thing to figure out. :)  I thought I was doing it correctly by adding `@property(nonatomic,retain) NSDictionary *dict;` to the .h file, but that doesn't seem to work. I'll keep plugging away at it -- thanks a ton for your insights.

Comment: Nevermind that last bit; I had forgotten to also add it under the `@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {` bit. No errors! Now let's see if I can do something useful with all this. :)

Comment: Mr. Rinser, you are a genius. I have complete functionality now! Cheers, mate; I'll probably be back with more questions soon. :D